# How to view pdf file from request? Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

i have made a small progress on my code and i want to share it with you, i want to view a pdf file on my screen.

my code:

```
Future loadPDF(APIurl)async {
    String? token = await this.storage.read(key: "token");
    Map<String,String> headers={
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + (token ?? ""),
    };
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        this.serverIP + ':' + this.serverPort +
            'api/v1/billing/billingPDF?month=4&year=2022&userID=6&cardID=60'),headers: headers);
    final bytes = response.bodyBytes;
     print(response.bodyBytes);
    

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you mean pdf viewer from url that you receive from your request, so you can use [syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer) or this [advance_pdf_viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/advance_pdf_viewer)